# C++ pointer to class object

Tags: c++, class

I encounter a strange issue when using class in C++.

Here is my code to add object the my linked list. I found that my V1 code works correct but V2 code doesn't and the printList can never stop in V2. Do anyone can explain why it is the case, since I expect V1 and V2 code should output the same outcome.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Node {
public:
    int data;
    Node *next;
    Node() {
        cout << "Node object is being created" << endl;
    }
};

void printList(Node *node) {
    while(node != NULL) {
        cout << node->data << ",";
        node = node->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void push(Node **node, int data) {

    // // working V1 start
    // Node *newNode = new Node();
    // newNode->data = data;
    // newNode->next = *node;
    // *node = newNode;
    // // working V1 end

    // not working V2 start
    Node newNode;
    newNode.data = data;
    newNode.next = *node;
    *node = &newNode;
    // not working V2 end

}

int main() {
    Node *a = NULL;

    push(&a, 15);
    push(&a, 10);

    printList(a);

}
```

Comment: Object in storage  `Node newNode` stops existing as soon as execution exits the scope (method's body) where it is declared. That's basics of language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your V2 stores a pointer to a node in automatic storage. That node is automatically destroyed at the end of the `push` function at which point the pointer is left dangling and no longer points to a valid object.

When you later attempt to indirect through that pointer, the behaviour of the program is undefined.

---

V1 does not have this problem, since it allocates the nodes in dynamic storage. Instead, the problem with V1 is that it leaks the allocated memory. Dynamic allocations created with `new`-expression need to be deallocated with `delete`-expression.

Answer (score 0):

The second code snippet has undefined behaviour because 1) the pointer `newNode` is not initialized and 2) you did not allocate memory where you are going to store values `data` and `*nod`e.

```
Node newNode;
newNode.data = data;
newNode.next = *node;
```

In the first code snippet a memory for the new node is allocated and the pointer is initialized by the address of the allocated memory

```
Node *newNode = new Node();
```

So these statements

```
newNode.data = data;
newNode.next = *node;
```

are valid and write data to the allocated memory.

Take into account that if to define the class the following way (removing the default constructor)

```
class Node {
public:
    int data;
    Node *next;
};
```

then the function can be written much simpler

```
void push( Node **node, int data )
{
    *node = new Node { data, *node };
}
```